# Downloaded files consistently disappearing from Internal Storage

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I have a Moto G Power running Android 11.

I like to listen to audiobooks, so I routinely download files from OneDrive, using the OneDrive app, to folders in my internal storage.

When I open the "My Files" app, I can go directly to Internal Storage. When I open Internal Storage it actually takes me to the folder "/storage/emulated/0/" I cannot go up to a higher folder. So I created a folder there called "Audiobooks" I create subfolders for each audiobook and I use an app (Smart Audiobook Reader) to read them.

When I download files, I go to OneDrive, find the audiobook mp3 files I'm looking for, select "Download" and then save it in the appropriate Audiobook subfolder. Also sometimes I download jpg files that serve at the "book covers" in the app.

All of this works well. I download new files every few days, 2 or 3 at a time.

However, over time, files in these folders start disappearing seemingly at random. Only the mp3 files, and it happens without me even know it so I'm not sure when the files are disappearing. I vaguely think it might have something to do with how long ago the file was downloaded and whether or not I accessed it recently, but in general, files start disappearing within 2 weeks or them being downloaded. It's only the MP3 files, and not the jpg files which leads me to believe a size issue too.

I've searched for solutions to this but no dice. This is what I've ruled out:

- It's not the audiobook app reader. I deleted it, installed a different one, and the problem continued to happen.
- It's not the Storage Manager under the Storage system settings. That feature is turned off.
- Files aren't hidden. I've selected to show hidden files in My files.

I feel like I've exhausted all of the usual suspects. So I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: You've missed another "usual suspect": the OneDrive app. Some "cloud storage apps" want to "help" you with storage management that way, as you always can get the stuff from "there". Not sure if this app is one of those (I'm not using it), but it would fit.

Comment: I did actually already check OneDrive. There is no setting in the app that cleans up files. Also, I'm not making the files "offline" to store them on my phone, I'm downloading them, so once downloaded they are outside of OneDrive's purview. I doubt the app could keep up with downloaded files to try to delete them, especially since they can be moved freely after download.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure it wasn't missed (I don't use any such cloud apps, so I couldn't tell).

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem ? Last month I suddenly observed files being disappeared from my android device shortly after I download them from google drive, and move them from downloads folder to custom directory.

Comment: I have the same issue with my pixel 7... I download mp3 files from my one drive which disappears after a few days. I do not like that at all...